# Verb that comes after "to"

Tags: verbs, infinitives

Why saying:

> "It is equivalent **to saying** that"

is true rather than:

> "It is equivalent **to say** that"

I always get confused about using the word after "to" because when I was learning English I was told that after to we have to use simple verb. Could you elaborate this for me?

Comment: As expressed in a comment to one of the answers, it's not necessarily incorrect to say the latter. In some contexts, it would be fine. It's only in general that the first would be used.

Answer (score 2):

"to" can introduce an infinitive, sometimes with the meaning of purpose, and it can also be a preposition. When it is a preposition, it is followed by V-ing.

In *It is equivalent to **saying** that...* "to" is a preposition, and the sentence means that something is the same as saying something else, for example:

- Walking out on your wife is equivalent to saying you don't love her anymore. (Walking out on your wife = saying you don't love her anymore)

When you establish the equivalence between two things, if one of those things is a verb it has to be a GERUND.

For the infinitive to work, we can think of other adjectives, for example:

*It is reasonable to **say** that this is a good method to learn English*.

In this case, "to say that..." is the infinitival subject of the sentence.

Comment: There probably are contexts in which "It is equivalent to say that..." works (something like, "It is a terrible thing to say that you hate puppies.  It is equivalent [as in, equally bad] to say you hate sunshine."), so you might want to moderate that claim.

Comment: @Juhasz: What do you mean? you are saying  "It is a terrible thing to saying that you hate puppies" is stronger that  "It is a terrible thing to say that you hate puppies.?"

Comment: @Saeed No, what Juhasz validly said is that it may be correct to say "It is equivalent to say..." when the adjective "equivalent" is not used to establish an equivalence but to mean "as ... as", for example: *To say you hate puppies is terrible. To say you hate sunshine is equivalent* (i.e. as terrible as saying you hate puppies). Therefore, it would be possible to say: "It's equivalent to say you hate sunshine". We cannot say "Saying you hate your puppy is equivalent to saying you hate sunshine" because those two sentences mean different things and are therefore not semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Because that is the kind of complement that *equivalent to* takes. (As Gustavson says, this is not an infinitive: *equivalent* does not take a direct object, but requires an indirect object with *to*).

*Like* takes the same kind of complement (eg "That is like riding a bike"). On the other hand, *necessary* takes an infinitive with *to* (eg "It is necessary to put a stamp on before posting").

There is no rule to this: you simply need to learn what each particular word requires. Sorry.

Comment: In my experience as a teacher, there are very few cases of the preposition "to" followed by gerund. Perhaps OP should learn those (*be devoted to, look forward to, come down to, get down to, be limited/confined/restricted to*, etc.).

Comment: @Gustavson: but equivalent does not come from the same family you mentioned, could you give me more example?

Comment: @Saeed There are certain adjectives followed by **to** and certain phrasal prepositional verbs with **to** that will be followed by the V-ing. The rule of thumb is, if you can use a noun, then you should use a gerund: *This is close to failure / This is close to being/becoming a failure.*

Comment: @Gustavson: are they exactly the same? with V-ing and without?

Comment: @Saeed Yes, but I don't know if you get my point. My point is that the V-ing is the nominal form of the verb and therefore equivalent to a noun. Another example: *Most of his time is devoted to solving mathematical problems / Most of his time is devoted to the solution of mathematical problems*. Can you see that "solving" is equivalent to "the solution of"?

Comment: @ Gustavson: Now it is clear to me.

Comment: @GustavsonI: came across to "The key to developing optimal algorithms is regularization." but I think it is correct to say that "The key to develop optimal algorithms is regularization." and it has the same meaning as the first one has.  Am I right? If I so, could you please explain it according to what have learned so far?

Comment: @Saeed: _The key to developing algorithms_ is natural. _The key to develop algorithms_ is not natural. In fact I cannot parse it the same way. As soon as I read _develop_ I know that this cannot be the construction "key to X" where X is the complement of "key". So I interpret "to" in another sense: something like "which you have to use in order to" (the same structure as "the way to develop" or "the place to develop" or "the money to develop", though the precise meaning of "to" is different in each of these cases). In this case the overall meaning is not so different, but it is very awkward.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Could you explain the concept of complement for me?

Comment: @Saeed: [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(linguistics)) begins "In grammar, a complement is a word, phrase or clause that is necessary to complete the meaning of a given expression.". They are distinguished from _adjuncts_ which are arguments which don't have to be there for the meaning. Direct objects of verbs are usually complements; but indirect objects may or may not be: _Give_ requires an indirect ("to") object as well as a direct one, so both are complements. But _walk_ can have a "to" object, but doesn't need one to complete its meaning.